# PEP8 naming convention on test classes

Tags: python, class, testing, pep8

I have been looking at [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [PEP8 -- Advanced Usage](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html) for clues on how to name my test classes. However, this is never mentioned on both sites, as well as many other sites I have looked at, such as the unittest page in the Python documentation. The only consistent style I see is "CapWords". In the unittest documentation they have examples for TestSequenceFunctions as well as DefaultWidgetSizeTestCase.

What I am trying to find out is whether to use "Name"Test or Test"Name". Methods use test_"name" and that's pretty much established. With regards to classes I am struggling to find a convention if there's one.

Would appreciate the forum's help on this.

Answer (score 29):

The [documentation for `unittest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example) suggests, e.g.:

```
class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_shuffle(self):
        ...

    def test_choice(self):
        ...
```

commenting

> The three individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters `test`. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.

Comment: Thanks. Tests themselves are not a problem because otherwise unittest won't pick them up.

Comment: In 2021 (hello new year), [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example) has not changed.

Answer (score 20):

Django and SQLAlchemy, two large, popular Python projects, both use "Name"Test(s). Personally, I prefer that to Test"Name", mainly because when there are multiple TestCases in a file, having each start with "Test" makes scanning difficult.

Not saying this equals a consensus, only two significant data points and a personal observation.

Comment: Thanks. I do agree with your reasoning.

Comment: I personally do this, and it's convenient for autocompleting things too.

Comment: That's a good point, but if you list symbols in a module (`Ctrl+Shift+O` in VS Code), it's much easier to find the test cases if they're `test`-prefixed because these lists are typically alphabetically sorted. Most autocomplete algorithms don't require you to start typing names from the beginning anymore either.